# Role instance name is not valid while restarting the VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-vm-role

I an have 8 node cluster setup in the Azure virtual network.

It was working fine until I shut down the virtual machines from the Azure Management Portal (shutdown icon/button).

After I stopped two virtual machines last week, I could not re-start them.

Friday evening I shutdown one more virtual machine to save on the costs, but today I am unable to start this virtual machine as well.

I see the following error:

> Failed to start virtual machine VM_NAME_HERE.
>
> Role instance name is not valid

Could anyone please suggest how to fix it?

I have also tried from Powershell with the same result.

Here is the console output:

```
VERBOSE: 1:33:16 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
VERBOSE: 1:33:16 PM - Begin Operation: Start-AzureVM
Start-AzureVM : ResourceNotFound : Role instance name is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-AzureVM -ServiceName MyServiceName -Name VMName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzureVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.StartAzureVMCommand

VERBOSE: 1:33:49 PM - Completed Operation: Start-AzureVM
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Regards,
JE

Comment: while this is pending, have you submitted an incident in the azure portal?

Comment: I did submit! No response form them.

Comment: In fact we bought subscription also so that they can reply :) But no use. They did not meet 8 hours SLA for replying!

Comment: You are saying 8 node cluster set, it Means you have created all VMs in same Cloud Service or you have created 8 VMs and configure traffic manager or setup any thing else

Comment: @subhashsingh: it's in the same cloud service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when resizing a VM.  My problem was resolved by going into
Azure Portal->Virtual Machines->Disks then selecting the disk attached to the VM in question(mine has only one disk) and finally selecting 'edit cache' at the bottom.  I just accepted what was already present in the popup and that was it.  The VM updated and restarted on its own.

Comment: Was facing the same issue... Kinda worked  for me... thanks! @RaySod

Answer (score 0):

It looks very weird, nevertheless the unique important thing in the VM is the disk (data) all other stuff is 'deletable' .

Try just creating another VMs with a compliant name and attach your current VM disk as main disk in the new ones.

Don't forget to delete the old VMs once the new start working.

Comment: Hi Juan, for this issue, we had to purchase the Azure support subscription and they fixed internally. I asked team acknowledged that it was an internal Issue of Azure and they are looking into option to reduce the occurrence of this known issue. Very very weird. :)